# How to print multidimentional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>
    var myJSONObject = {"onw": [ {"name": "nitin", "age": "31", "sal": "4000"},{"name1": "nilesh", "age": "11", "sal": "14000"}]};
    document.write(myJSONObject['onw']);
//document.write(myJSONObject.onw.name);
    </script>
```

o/p:
undefined

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: 1. Don't use `document.write`. Ever. 2. You're trying to write an array (try `myJSONObject.onw[0].name` instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean how to print each onw's info ?
You can use

```
document.write(myJSONObject['onw'][0].name);
```

this method to combine